# How do I remove the 0 once a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, when I click either `1` or `2` the `0` in the `display` will be overwritten with the button clicked.

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)

  function showNumber() {
    display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="display">0</div>
    <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
    <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code snippet? I've tried your code in fiddle and had no error: https://jsfiddle.net/edn6gcfh/

Comment: If you don't want to concatenate, don't use `+=`. Consider using `=` instead?

Comment: I still need the +=, but at the same time, I don't want the 0 to appear after I click the buttons.

Comment: Add a variable firstClick, if true it's '=' else it's '+='

Comment: Do you want to concatenate strings or total numbers?

Comment: Have you tried using <input class="number" type="submit" value="1"> Then you can use  jQuery val().

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add an `if` statement states that if there is `0` in the `display`
remove it before adding anything like `if (display.textContent == 0){display.innerHTML = "";}` just the following

### Example

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)

  function showNumber() {
    if (display.textContent == 0){
      display.innerHTML = "";
    }
    display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="display">0</div>
    <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
    <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Or simply if you want to overwrite everything means that before adding anything in the DOM just remove everthing you can simply try the following

### Example

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)

  function showNumber() {
    display.innerHTML = "";
    display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="display">0</div>
    <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
    <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your button texts are always numericals, and that the displayed result should be the number formed by those digits.

You can convert the result to number (using unary `+`) and assign that:

```
display.textContent = +(display.textContent + numberButtons.textContent)
```

NB: it is better practice to reserve the use of `innerHTML` for when you need to support HTML encoded strings. Otherwise use `textContent`.

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)

  function showNumber() {
    display.innerHTML = +(display.innerHTML + numberButtons.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="display">0</div>
  <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
  <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I still need the +=, but at the same time, I don't want the 0 to
> appear after I click the buttons.

You can check if **display.innerHTML** is 0. So can decide if concatenate or substitute the string.

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
    numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)

    function showNumber() {
        if (display.innerHTML == '0') {
            display.innerHTML = numberButtons.innerHTML
        } else {
            display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="display">0</div>
    <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
    <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This still concatenates...?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you explain? If I click button 1 the handler produces 1111111111  Where was I wrong? thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Right.